# How can I alias `...` to `../..` in Bash?

Tags: bash, alias

How can I alias `...` to `../..` in Bash?

I am aware that other answers allow `alias '...'='cd ../..'` but I'd like to be able to address the directory two levels up with other commands, allowing for:

```bash
cd ...
ls ...
realpath ...
```

I have tried `alias '...'='../..'` but when trying to use this I get the following:

```bash
$ alias '...'='../..'
$ type ...
... is aliased to `../..'
$ cd ...
bash: cd: ...: No such file or directory
```

Comment: this question fits better on https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: `bind '" ...": " ../.."'`

Comment: Cross-posted on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746047/how-can-i-alias-to-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define functions, example for `cd`:

```
cd() { [[ $1 == ... ]] && command cd ../.. || command cd "$@"; }
```

You can put it in `~/.bashrc` and source it: `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

Gilles answer allows you to apply `...` by checking if the first param equals `...` and then hardcoding the paramter.

---

You could reverse the command, where you pass the `command` you wish to run with `../..`:

```
function ...() {
    [[ -z "$1" ]] && printf "No command given\n" && return 0;
    $@ ../..
}
```

Usage:

```
... cd
... ls -lta
```